# Get the Child Class Propert in Parent class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I had a two controllers in my application with database first approach

> SampCutReqMaster.CS

```
public partial class SampCutReqMaster
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public SampCutReqMaster()
        {
            this.SamCutAssignmentMasters = new HashSet<SamCutAssignmentMaster>();
        }

        public decimal SampCutreqID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> BuyerID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> PatternRefID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> PatternStyleID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> SampleTypeID { get; set; }


        public virtual BuyerMaster BuyerMaster { get; set; }
        public virtual PatternStyle PatternStyle { get; set; }
        public virtual PatterRefMaster PatterRefMaster { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<SamCutAssignmentMaster> SamCutAssignmentMasters { get; set; }
        public virtual SampleType SampleType { get; set; }
    }
```

and The next is

> SamCutAssignmentMaster

```
 public partial class SamCutAssignmentMaster
    {
        public decimal CutAssignID { get; set; }
        public decimal SampCutreqID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime ReceivedDate { get; set; }
        public string ReceivedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> PatternMasterID { get; set; }                 

        public virtual PatternMaster PatternMaster { get; set; }
        public virtual SampCutReqMaster SampCutReqMaster { get; set; }
    }
```

I had created a controller with a index view for  SampCutReqMaster

```
public class SampCutReqMastersController : Controller
    {
        private ArtEntities db = new ArtEntities();
    // GET: SampCutReqMasters
    public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var sampCutReqMasters = db.SampCutReqMasters.Include(s => s.BuyerMaster).Include(s => s.PatternStyle).Include(s => s.PatterRefMaster).Include(s => s.SampleType).Include(s=>s.SamCutAssignmentMasters);

            var sampCutReqMasterssort = sampCutReqMasters.ToList().OrderByDescending(a => a.AddedDate);
            return View(sampCutReqMasterssort.ToList());
        }
}
```

I want to get the "receivedBy" of SamcutAssignmentMaster(child class) in my  view of SamCutReqMaster (Parent).But there may be no data in SamcutAssignmentMaster relavant to  SamCutReqMaster (FK is SamCutReqID)

In Index view Below I need to access SamcutAssignmentMaster.receivedBy

```
   @model IEnumerable<WebArtSampler.Models.SampCutReqMaster>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReqNum)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fabric)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SampleRequiredDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AddedDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AddedBy)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BuyerMaster.BuyerName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PatternStyle.StyleName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PatterRefMaster.PatterRefNum)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SampleType.SampleType1)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SizeDetail)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Qty)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReqNum)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fabric)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SampleRequiredDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AddedDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AddedBy)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BuyerMaster.BuyerName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PatternStyle.StyleName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PatterRefMaster.PatterRefNum)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SampleType.SampleType1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SizeDetail)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qty)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.SampCutreqID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.SampCutreqID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.SampCutreqID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Please show us real working code. This will never compile

Comment: Do you know what a partial class is? It has not much to do with inheritance

Comment: @Mardoxx I know.. But I am able to get values of almost all other virtual class properties.  like   item.PatterRefMaster.PatterRefNum   in view. I am  not able to access properties of  SamCutAssignmentMasters only which is in Icollection   public virtual ICollection<SamCutAssignmentMaster> SamCutAssignmentMasters { get; set; }

Comment: So what happens when you attempt to code "modelItem => item.SamcutAssignmentMaster.receivedBy".. Does the intellisense not bring up the received by property... or is it the collection itself?

Comment: No intellisence is not bringing received by property ,its bring item.SamcutAssignmentMaster which is Icollection. I was wondering if I can get to the "receivedby " from ICollection object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. You can't access the properties whilst your type is still as the interface ICollection. You need to cast it to a concrete type before you can access the properties of the collection via an index.

```
 @for (var adCounter = 0; adCounter <= (Model.SamCutAssignmentMasters.Count - 1); adCounter++)
 {
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => ((List<SamCutAssignmentMaster>)x.SamCutAssignmentMasters)[adCounter].ReceivedBy)
 }
```

Cast the type to a list as per the above and you should see the properties.

NOTE: You are using DisplayFor in your view. If you intend to post the contents of this view the model will not bind unless you have a hidden control for each item or you switch to TextBoxFor. You will also need the for (Counter) syntax as well to bind to items in collections.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Wheels. I need it Just for display purpose and I will not be posting. I had made some changes and used it inside the view..      @Html.DisplayFor(x => ((List<WebArtSampler.Models.SamCutAssignmentMaster>)item.SamCutAssignmentMasters)[i].ReceivedBy)     But getting error Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[WebArtSampler.Models.SamCutAssignmentMaster]' to type

Comment: @SreenathGanga - Is there a reason for the HashSet? This is to ensure there are no duplicates in the ICollection. You set the SamCutAssignmentMasters to a new HashSet when you call the constructor for SampCutReqMaster. Perhaps just use a list to start of with if you have no special constraints to enforce?